# How to change legends entries using macro

Tags: excel, vba

There are several data series in the chart and also for each of them there is a trend line. I want legend to include the original data series only not the trend lines. I was wondering if legends has a property I could edit

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim theChart As Worksheet
Dim oChart As ChartObject
Dim mySeries As Series
Dim objTrendline As Trendline

For Each oChart In theChart.ChartObjects
    For Each mySeries In oChart.Chart.SeriesCollection
        mySeries.Trendlines.Add
        objTrendline = mySeries.Trendlines(1)
        ' now just set the trendline legend label to blank
        objTrendline.Name = ""
    Next mySeries
Next oChart
```